# How do you prove the arithmetic mean of vertices of a polygon lies in itself?

Tags: geometry, polygons

There's an n-sided convex polygon with vertices denoted by $A_1(x_1,y_1),A_2(x_2,y_2)..A_n(x_n,y_n)$. Now we draw a point $P(\frac{\sum x_i}{n},\frac{\sum y_i}{n})$, then how do you show that $P$ must be in the polygon, or is there any counterexample?

Comment: You can prove by induction and definition of convexity. Start with triangle.

Comment: @Shailesh How can I do my first step from triangle to quadrilateral? Any hint of property of convexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the vertex V closest to P. Since the polygon is convex, there must exist a line through V such that all of the vertices are on one side of the line (or on the line), while P is on the other side. This clearly contradicts that P is the arithmetic mean, since you can just rotate the coordinate system such that the y-axis is perpendicular to the line in question. This means that the x-coordinate of P is less than the smallest x-coordinate of a vertex, an impossibility. Drawing a picture will make this more clear.

Comment: > there must exist a line through V such that all of the vertices are on one side of the line (or on the line), while P is on the other side.  I do confused about this. Though it is convex, if $P$ just lies in it, how can all the vertex is on one side but $P$ is on the other side?

Comment: @YiFei If you're talking about the case where $P$ is on an edge of the polygon and wish to prove that such a scenario can't happen, then my statement would read "while $P$ is on the other side or on the line". The average would have to be on the side of the line that contains the vertices, and this requirement is strict (It can't be on the line, or else all of the x-coordinates are 0 and thus the polygon is degenerate).

Comment: I think I'm more focusing on that $P$ can't be out of the polygon, i.e. $P$ should be in the region bounded by those vertices, and hence $P$ should be on the same side as it of the vertices. Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @YiFei I did a proof by contradiction. If P is outside of the polygon, and you arrange the coordinate system like shown, then you prove that the x coordinate of P is less than the average x coordinate.